# connecting to MySQL database that is on another system through R (my system is windows and the database is on UBUNTU)

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to connect to mysql database that is on another system which has os ubuntu and i get errors saying "cant connect to database..unknown mysql server host " . my system is windows.  what am i missing out on? this is my code by the way. All required packages have been installed. i have provided the right user name and password. this is the ip address. the database that i am trying to connect to is on another system.

```
`drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")

con <- dbConnect(drv,
             dbname = "dda",
             host = '*.*.*.*',
             user = "*",
             password = "*" ) `
```

Comment: Can you connect to your MySQL instance from the command line using these connection parameters?  I'll bet you can't, meaning that something is wrong.

Comment: Well, i know that. What is it that is wrong? I dont know what i am missing out on

Comment: You need to make sure the connection works before you start connecting to it through R. And that really isn't a programming question _per se_, but rather a question for an infrastructure team. The database may be configured to for example not accept connections from your IP/port.

Comment: thank you so much. i had the same doubt that this is an admin problem but just wanted to confirm